# Reuse a DbContext within a single request?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext

**TL;DR** How can I use a scoped `DbContext` to make multiple queries within a single request?

I'm brand-new to EntityFrameworkCore, and I'm having trouble with `DbContext`, which I'm adding to the DI container using `AddScoped` (though I'm not wedded to this, it's just what I've read online as the right thing to do).

I have a `WidgetRepository` that allows me to look up `Widget`s by id or by manufacturer id, like so:

```cs
public class WidgetRepository
{
    private readonly WidgetDbContext _widgetDbContext;

    public WidgetRepository(WidgetDbContext widgetDbContext)
    {
        _widgetDbContext = widgetDbContext;
    }

    public Widget FindById(string id)
    {
        using (var context = _widgetDbContext)
        {
            var widget = context.Widget.Include("Identifiers")
                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id.Equals(id));
            return widget;
        }
    }

    public IList<Widget> FindByManufacturerId(string manufacturerId)
    {
        using (var context = _widgetDbContext)
        {
            var widgets = context.Widget.Include("Identifiers")
                .Where(w => w.Identifiers.SingleOrDefault(identifier => identifier.Type.Equals("manufacturerId") && identifier.Value.Equals(manufacturerId)));
            return widgets;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to allow the user to enter an id without my knowing in advance whether it's a widget id or a manufacturer id. So I have the following class that does this:

```cs
public class SearchById
{
    private readonly WidgetRepository _widgetRepository;

    public SearchById(WidgetRepository widgetRepository)
    {
        _widgetRepository = widgetRepository;
    }

    public IList<Widget> Search(string id)
    {
        var widget = _widgetRepository.FindById(id);

        if (widget != null) {
            return new List<Widget> {widget};
        }

        else return _widgetRepository.FindByManufacturerId(id);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when `_widgetRepository` returns from `FindById`, it disposes of its `WidgetDbContext`, which means that when I make the subsequent call to `FindByManufacturerId`, the `WidgetDbContext` no longer exists.

How can I make the `WidgetDbContext` reusable for multiple queries across the entire request?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're disposing the DbContext in each method of the WidgetRepository class. Don't do that.

You should let the DI container manage the lifespan of the DbContext. It will created new instances and dispose old ones based on how you registered them (e.g. AddScoped in you sample).

Remove the using statements in those methods and you should be able to perform multiple calls against the same context in the same scope (just be careful not to access if from a different thread).